# R: How can I create a polygon from several polygons and a line?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, ggplot2

I have some spatial objects that I want to combine, namely three polygons and a line. The ultimate goal is to create a polygon that I can overlay on an area of a map of administrative divisions of the UK to highlight a certain zone.

If it were a case of combining four polygons, I would have a number of options, but as one of the objects is a line I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to tackle it. I would have thought combining polygons and lines would be a common operation but it seems not.

Here's the map produced by my code (see below).

[image: overview]

The red line starts and ends on the coastline or, strictly speaking, on the bank of a river leading to an estuary at the south end, as can be seen in the following images.

[image: north end]

[image: south end]

So, because there is an intersection I assume it is possible to group the elements together, I just don't know now. To summarise...

[image: summary]

Code follows:

```
library(httr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

response <- GET(url="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4115850/spobjects.rda")
load(rawConnection(response$content))

class(dist.shape) # map with administrative divisions
class(terr.shape) # line defining the landward side of the zone
head(dist.df) # data frames created using fortify() function
head(terr.df) # ditto

ggplot(data = dist.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
     geom_polygon(colour = "grey50", fill = "grey80", size = 0.5) +
     geom_path(data = terr.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               colour = "red", size = 0.5) +
     theme()
```

Answer (score 2):

gUnion in the rgeos library will merge polygon and line geometries.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. `rgeos` was full of interesting things to try but ultimately I couldn't get R to generate a polygon composed of the line and subsets of the other polygons as described above. In the end I manually added the line in QGIS on a different layer, merged the layer, snipped pieces off it and exported it as a shapeful.